# bxslider zooms in when changing page (url)

Tags: image, bxslider, zooming

I have a problem with bxslider.
Sometimes if you change the page on the website, the image of bxslider zooms in. This should not happen, it should stay normal.

**Link of Website: `raumdimension.ch`**

The BXSlider is installed on the Following:

```
http://raumdimension.ch/

http://raumdimension.ch/visualisierungen.html
http://raumdimension.ch/visualisierungen/architekturvisualisierungen.html
http://raumdimension.ch/visualisierungen/produktevisualisierungen.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Bxslider performs as expected if **li element have only one child**. Just wrap the content you have within a simple div element. See this [typographic site](http://www.tipografix.ro/) where bxslider behaves as you want.